# Android: Vector has blur on android 4.4

Tags: android, image, vector, drawable, android-4.4-kitkat

There `TextView` and I want him to do `VectorDrawable` background. I do `vector.xml`

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="114.0"
    android:viewportWidth="494.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M12,86.61L2.19,76.51L12,67.18L12,8C12,3.58 15.59,0 20.01,0L483.99,0C488.42,0 492,3.58 492,8L492,102C492,106.42 488.41,110 483.99,110L20.01,110C15.58,110 12,106.42 12,102L12,86.61Z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

and this `VectorDrawable` on android 4.4 has a fuzzy edge (not clear), but on android 5.0+ everything looks good (as needed).

Help solve the problem with android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Use this when using ImageView

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" /> <- This may help
```

Vector Drawables are also supported in cases like `TextView's drawableLeft` property

*(with custom Textview to handle vector for PreLollipop version).*